# Network location returned is wrong

Tags: android, location

I want to get the location of the user using network. This is my code

```
package com.example.locationtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;

public class WhereAmI extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

        Criteria crta = new Criteria();
        crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        crta.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        crta.setBearingRequired(false);
        crta.setCostAllowed(true);
        crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true);

        // String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        updateWithNewLocation(location);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
                locationListener);
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

    };

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        String timeStamp = (String) DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss",
                new java.util.Date());
        String locationString = location.getLatitude() + ", "
                + location.getLongitude();

        Log.i("Main", "Time = " + timeStamp + " Location = " + locationString);
    }
}
```

This code works with my nexus 4, but if I use it with my Galaxy Gio the location is off by 30 Miles..

Answer (score 0):

network location is based on the nearest Cell tower which the phone is connected to. It could be possible that your Nexus4 is connected to one Cell tower and the Galaxy Gio connected to another cell tower that could be like a bit far from where the Device is. To get an accurate fix, use GPS_PROVIDER. I had this issue before when using a NETWORK_PROVIDER. Got rid of it when I started using the GPS_PROVIDER which gave me accurate fixes